# Customizing header's title

Tags: header-footer

How do I to make this header text takes this form `Chapitre 1. Spécification des besoins` ?

**EDIT :** Transformation : CHAPITRE 1. SPECIFICATION DES BESOINS >> Chapitre 1. Spécification des besoins

[image]

Comment: Should this be on every page or just on even/odd ones?

Comment: @GonzaloMedina, left header of each page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [`fancyhdr`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/fancyhdr) package:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[french]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\pagestyle{fancy}

\fancyhf{}
\fancyhead[L]{\nouppercase\leftmark}
\fancyfoot[C]{\thepage}

\begin{document}

\chapter{Spécification des besoin}
\lipsum[1-40]

\end{document}
```

The header:

[image]

Since no information was given about the position of the page number, I placed it at the center in the footer, but this can be changed as needed.

Comment: I've edited my post.

Comment: @user3289501 please see my updated answer.

Comment: `Chapitre 1. Spécification des besoins`

Comment: @user3289501 Yes, see the new edit.

Comment: OK, I'll delete mine...

Comment: @karlkoeller Oh, I'm so sorry about that.

Comment: Oh, come on. +1 for being quicker in modifying the answer. You can always upvote another question of mine ;-)